# Brush functionality in my d3 line chart is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg

My implementation for Brush & Zoom functionality in my d3 line chart is not working as expected,

I followed this link - https://bl.ocks.org/EfratVil/92f894ac0ba265192411e73f633a3e2f,

Problems what I am facing is -

chart is not showing all the values, I have 4 data but it only shows 3 data
onClick of dot I am showing the rect which is not moving with the brush functionality 
minor thing but chart always goes out of the box

My code sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-firefly-xy1py

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong? thanks.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lamzH.png]

Please suggest me what I am doing wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first point is going behind your `clip` area. For example, if you right click on the first visible circle and inspect element you will see all 4 circle elements are present in the dom. The first circle element is behind the axis.

This means you have to move your plot to the right. Unfortunately, the way you have coded the chart you have not appended a `g` element for the main chart and then appended the circles and path to that `g` element. As a result this has to be done in multiple places.

First we adjust your clip path as:

```
   svg
      .append("defs")
      .append("SVG:clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("SVG:rect")
      .attr("width", containerWidth)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("x", 40)
      .attr("y", 0);
```

next we adjust your circles

```
    scatter
      .selectAll(".foo")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "foo")
      .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)")
```

and then your line

```
    scatter
      .append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");
```

You will have to account for this `40` px translate for your other elements as well. Although I am having a hard time destructuring your svg. I think this should give you the idea though. Check the axis matches the time points as well.

Check the [code sand box](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-wildflower-3gmhz)

**Update**

To make the rectangles move with the brush, you will have to add code to your `brushed` const function to recalculate the x, y, width and height using the updated scales.

**Update2**

After going through the codesandbox presented in the comments I was able to add the code to update the rectangles to the `brushed` const as below to make the rects also move with the brushing:

```
      // update rectangles
      scatter
        .selectAll(".rect-elements")
        .attr("x", d => {
          console.log(d);
          return xScale(d.startTime) - 12.5;
        })
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", 24)
        .attr("height", height + 5);
```

[Full working Code Sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-cartwright-k8t4w)

Comment: I have given the almost 50px translate to my other elements as well, it looks good, 

https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-firefly-xy1py

Making the changes for the rectangles and lines to move with the brush

Comment: I am trying to make the changes for the rectangles and lines to move with the brush, but I am facing some difficulties can you please check my codesandbox please guide me.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. Let me have a look at it.

Comment: Sure let me know if you have any other quesitons. If not please mark it as answered.

Comment: Most of the elements I have added in brushed code, https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-firefly-xy1py

Only clickLine element on click of dot what I am appending is not coming properly, if you can please have a look and guide me. I am sure for you this will be easy catch, thanks.

Comment: Check this out. https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-hill-jivth 
You should only append the line once and then update as necessary. Since the data of the `clickLine` is not propagated in the brush nor bound to the line, I attach the data using an attribute `data-time` to the `clickLine`. Then in the brush I retrieve this value and use it to calculate new `x1` and `x2` positions. Also please mark as answer.

Comment: I have a query if you would like to answer,  last and first circle is not coming properly. 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60865922/d3-chart-is-going-out-of-the-box-last-circle-is-not-coming-properly