# d3 chart is going out of the box, last circle is not coming properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

My Chart is going out of the box, If you notice last circle is cutting and going out of the described width,
I have tried to give transform but it's not looking good,

```
scatter
  .append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50,0)")
  .attr("d", line);

scatter
      .selectAll(".foo")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "foo")
      .attr("transform", "translate(50,0)")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.startTime);
      })
```

I tried to give `.attr("transform", "translate(50,0)")` but then first circle was cutting off.
How I can shrink/transform a little so both the first and last points looks good and i have some space as well.

Can someone point what I am missing ?

Code sand box here - https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-firefly-xy1py

[image]

Thanks..

Comment: This is because the point's value is near 0 and the whole chart is clipped by ´clipPath id="clip"´ In order to understand what happens please inspect the chart and in the inspector go to `<g class="focus2"` and delete the `clip-path` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion in the comments provided for answer by richardwestenra, we came up with an alternative solution which reduces the `margin.right` from the `width` in a number of places to make the plot appear within the drawing area and not be clipped by the clip path.

The solution is at https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-mcclintock-hsmgu

Comment: Hi Coola,

Would like to answer this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61203923/in-my-d3-chart-zoom-selection-disappears-when-i-change-the-brush-and-click-on-n

Comment: Hi Coola,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048007/how-to-reset-the-d3-selection-of-point

Can you help me with this query ? it's new question.

Comment: Can you help me with this ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558856/how-to-use-scaletime-to-horizontally-position-a-background-rectangle

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the width of your clip path is the problem:

```
svg
  .append("defs")
  .append("SVG:clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("SVG:rect")
  .attr("width", containerWidth)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("x", 40)
  .attr("y", 0);
```

It's currently at the same width as your overall SVG container, when it should be the width of the chart clip area (i.e. `containerWidth - margin.left - margin.right`). It's offset from the left with `.attr("x", 40)` so it's still clipping the line and circles from the left, but this means that it's extending beyond the right edge of the SVG by 40px so it's not clipping anything on the right side.

Try changing `.attr("width", containerWidth)` to `.attr("width", width)`.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed it, but as I am noticing last point is not displaying, I have 3 data in my chart but only 2 is coming up, https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-firefly-xy1py. any suggestions  ?

Comment: Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-mcclintock-hsmgu

Comment: Thanks, @Coola do you want to post this as an answer I will mark the answer as Accepted. we have reduced the right margin from the width `(width - margin.right) ` for zoom scale and brush.

Comment: Thanks @richardwestenra for you suggestion as well. +1

Comment: Hi  richard,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048007/how-to-reset-the-d3-selection-of-point

Can you help me with this query ? it's new question.

Comment: @richard, Can you help me with this ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558856/how-to-use-scaletime-to-horizontally-position-a-background-rectangle