# In my d3 chart, Zoom selection disappears when I change the brush and click on not selected range

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In my d3 chart, Zoom selection disappears when I change the brush and click on not selected range.

This is my working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-shirley-cxq99

[image]

When I changed the selection above and clicked on unselected selection zoom selection disappear.

[image]

Please guide me what is wrong with my code.

Comment: This is probably happening because once you change your selection above, the unselected area is where you can click and drag and let go to create a new selection zone. Do you not want that?

Comment: @Coola, This is expected we want to click and drag to create the new selection, but if I only click it should not hide the selection until I click and drag to some selection, In below URL you can check the expected behaviour I am trying to achieve .
https://bl.ocks.org/EfratVil/92f894ac0ba265192411e73f633a3e2f

Comment: I am a bit confused by what your end goal is. Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I suppose you mean why is the green overlay disappearing?

Comment: @Coola Yes correct,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just un-comment this part in your code to actually produce the zoom rect, which gets used in the `brushed` function.

```
    svg
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "zoom")
      .attr("width", containerWidth - 20)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,20)")
      .call(zoom);
```

See working [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-cookies-1tsce?file=/src/TimelineChart.js:21635-21828)

Comment: I got the problem thanks, I was not adding zoom intensely because I don't want user to do the zoom from the chart with cursor.  so I am not calling `.call(zoom);` But because of this my chart click functionality on dot doesn't work.

Comment: Modified code - https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-shirley-cxq99
`scatter
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "zoom")
      .attr("width", containerWidth - 20)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,20)");` changed `svg` to `scatter` and it's working, and moved this code before `scatter
      .selectAll(".rect-elements")` this code.
I am not calling `.call(zoom)` is it correct ?

Comment: The question is it correct depends on what your final aim is. It seems to be working for you and on my end I do not see any errors either. If you do not need zoom do not call it.

Comment: Can you help me with this ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558856/how-to-use-scaletime-to-horizontally-position-a-background-rectangle